# Embedding custom metadata with Service Fabric application/service

Tags: azure-service-fabric

The objective that I have is to run multiple applications with some metadata embedded into applications/services so that I could query applications/services using the metadata. Is this possible?

I was looking at the following [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456775/publishing-metadata-to-service-fabric/34502373#34502373) and the answer hints at this possibility, but no specific details on how to achieve the result.

Comment: When you say query applications/services using the metadata, do you mean allowing a client to search for a specific service based on available metadata? Do you have a specific example of what you'd like to do?

Comment: Correct. In the post I've referenced, you referred to fabric://app/service/property uri and I wasn't sure how to get that going and what a "property" value is. Example: might have multiple applications that belong to a logical "environment". If need to query all those services, how would I go about it is not clear. That's why I was thinking about custom metadata.

Comment: @VaclavTurecek is that what you wanted to clarify?

Comment: Yeah, that helps, thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primary piece of "metadata" you get is the service/application instance name. That's what I talked about in my other [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34456775/publishing-metadata-to-service-fabric/34502373#34502373). The way that works is by creating each service/application instance with a name that contains some information clients can use when resolving them. Clients can then query Service Fabric for named application/service instances and connect to a specific one. A service/application instance name is URI, so you can use a path hierarchy to categorize information.

Continuing with the audio/video example: Let's extend that example so we have an application that can perform specific tasks for specific media formats for audio or video. Each combination of task + media format is a unique named service instance, resulting in a deployment that looks something like this:

```
Application:
fabric:/avapp
  Services:
  fabric:/avapp/video/encoding/mp4
  fabric:/avapp/video/encoding/h264
  fabric:/avapp/video/captioning/english
  fabric:/avapp/video/captioning/czech
  fabric:/avapp/audio/encoding/aac
  fabric:/avapp/audio/encoding/mp3
  etc.
```

Now clients can query Service Fabric to discover what services are available:

```
FabricClient fabricClient = new FabricClient();

System.Fabric.Query.ServiceList services = await fabricClient.QueryManager.GetServiceListAsync(new Uri("fabric:/avapp"));
```

Then you can simply query the list of services with LINQ. For example, if I want to see all services that do video encoding:

```
services.Where(x => x.ServiceName.AbsolutePath.Contains("video/encoding"));
```

And then you can resolve an address for a specific service to connect to it:

```
ServicePartitionResolver resolver = ServicePartitionResolver.GetDefault();
ResolvedServicePartition servicePartition = await resolver.ResolveAsync(new Uri("fabric:/avapp/video/encoding/h264"), new ServicePartitionKey(1), cancellationToken);
ResolvedServiceEndpoint endpoint = servicePartition.GetEndpoint();
```

There's a bit more to the address resolution part ([see here](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/service-fabric-reliable-services-communication/)), but that's the general idea.

Application instances also allow you to set custom application parameters (key-value pairs) that can be set per instance at creation time. They don't show up in the application name, but you get that information back when you ask Service Fabric for a list of running application instances. That can potentially also be used as metadata by clients when they need to decide what application to connect to.

**Update:** More info on application instance parameters:

When you [create a new application instance](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt161331.aspx) you can supply a set of key-value pairs in the [application description](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.description.applicationdescription.aspx). Then when you [query Service Fabric for application instances](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt161405.aspx) you get back a list of [Application](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.fabric.query.application.aspx) result objects that have said parameters. This also shows up in Visual Studio, in your application project, where you have environment-specific application parameter files. Visual Studio extracts those key-value pairs from the XML files and uses them in the application description when it creates an instance of your application.

[image]

Comment: Great info, thank you so much. Could you please point where the info on key/value pairs and querying can be found? That scenario is exactly what I'd be probably ending up doing.

Comment: No problem, updated my answer with more info on application parameters.

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for the detailed info. Especially for mentioning code and manifest approaches both.

Comment: One important detail: ApplicationParameters will only work if a default is pecified in ApplicationPackageRoot :)